# How can i resize my google programmable search engine to be more mobile friendly?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, google-search

I have my google programmable search engine looking and working great on a computer browser:

[image]

But on mobile it scrunches up:

[image]

I have tried to adjust the height and width or resize it to look good on mobile, but have had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

## Using media queries

Media queries allow you to apply CSS styles depending on a device's general type (such as computer vs. mobile) or other characteristics such as screen resolution or browser viewport width.

In your case, I would use media queries to check the viewport's (screen) width. Based on the different width's I would modify the search engine's style.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {  // Apply to any screen with smaller width than 600px
  .search-head {
    // My personal recommendation, you can modify it as you want.
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    margin-right: 5vw;
  }
}
```

You can set different width's for the search engine depending on the screen width:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1200px) {
  .search-head {
    width: 30vw;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:900px) {
  .search-head {
    width: 40vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and response! I will implement them and hopefully they fix my issue. Have a great day!

Comment: You are welcome. With media queries, you can adjust the search engine for any device width. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi again, I have implemented your suggestions but sadly the search bar is still too tall. Ive added the height property but it does nothing.

Comment: Too tall? I thought you were having problems with the width. 
Well, with media queries, you can set the height and width for any screen size.

Comment: Was having both height and width issues with mobile as seen in the second image, it is both too tall (the giant white background) and not wide enough. I've tried to adjust the height but it does nothing, its as if I didn't even add a height property.

Comment: Well, the search engine looks different on other OS. But after further inspection, I believe setting `.gsc-control-cse { padding:0 }` will remove the padding.

Comment: Also, you may consider setting this: `.gsc-control-cse { border: 0; background-color: none; }`

Comment: I have used .gsc-control-cse { padding: 0, border: 0; background-color: none;} but the background-color: none; does nothing.

Comment: And do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Update. I added "height:0;" to .gsc-control-cse and was able to remove the background successfully.... Now on to trying to resize the height of the entire thing

Comment: Is the height so bad? From my perspective, it looks fine. You just need to adjust the width.

Comment: Yes, it is pushing the footer content down and over, so both a height and width fix is needed

Comment: Can you provide the full code?

Comment: For the entire page, I am unable to due to privacy reasons but i can pull out the snippets that relate to the search bar and footer if that works?

Comment: Yeah that would work

Comment: okay i will update the post now :)

Comment: code has been added :)

Comment: I am little confused from your approach to style the footer. Are you familiar with flexbox?

Comment: No i am not very familiar with flexbox. I have heard of it before but never really worked with it, i was taught to mostly use grid layouts.

Comment: Do you have viewport meta tag in your html's `head`?
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Comment: Yes I do have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />  under my htmls <head>

Comment: UPDATE!!!! I was finally able to get both height and width resized after a lot of trial and error. Thank you so much for your help and communication @OfficialVysko !!

Comment: You're welcome. If media queries helped you, please mark my answer as accepted :)
Have a great day

Comment: They sadly did not, I had to keep targeting different classes until it rendered correctly.

Comment: That's weird... on mi side it works with your code fine. I can adjust the width's and height's for any screen size. :D

Comment: Yeahhhh im not sure what the issue was, when i added in your suggested code it changed nothing. Then i played around with the widths/heights and still... nothing lol. I was able to just use chromes inspect feature and clicked from div to div, class to class until i found the correct one them then adjusted the width and height. I am still not 100% happy with the search bar in the footer on mobile but it is a lot better then it was. Thank you for your effort, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well consider using flexbox instead of margin and float.